# How to reset a XenCentre terminal emulator (shows junk)

Tags: linux, xenserver, xencenter

While accessing a linux virtual machine through XenCentre 6's console tab, I mistakenly cat'd binary to `stdout` (control characters included). Using the `reset` command in the terminal doesn't redraw the screen with the correct characters.

I suspect that it's XenCenter's terminal emulator that needs to be reset.

I've also tried running:

```
   stty sane
   tput rs1
```

The VM is Centos 5.11

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the ansi escape sequence does the trick.

```
echo -e "\033c"
```